# installing f# powerpack (vs2012)

Tags: visual-studio, f#, f#-powerpack

probably it is a silly question, never the less, here it is (I am new to f# and VS):

I had downloaded the f#powepack installer from codeplex and ran it. It was "successfully" installed and the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharpPowerPack-4.0.0.0 was created.

Now, if I write

`open Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing`

in VS, I am told that the namespace lexing is not defined. Indeed, after

`open Microsoft.FSharp.`

the only options to continue are: Collections; Control; Core; Data; Linq; NativeInteropt; Quotations; Reflection

Next I tried to install the "F# Parsed Language Starter" tutorial. Well, after editing the vsixmanifest file so that it would run with VS 11 and renaming the folder

C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharpPowerPack-4.0.0.0

to

C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharpPowerPack-2.0.0.0

I was finally able to open the "F# Parsed Language Starter" project in VS. Of course it wouldn't compile. The following error was given:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\FSharpPowerPack-2.0.0.0\bin\FSharp.PowerPack.targets(32,3):
>   Fehler MSB6004: Der angegebene Speicherort der ausführbaren Datei der
>   Aufgabe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\fslex.exe" ist ungültig.

this somehow reinforced my suspicion that f#powerpack was not properly installed.

actual question:

1. How to test whether f#powerpack is installed correctly
2. what did I do wrong? (and how do it correctly)

Comment: Why the closing/downwoting and reference to the FAQ?

after all, quoting the FAQ:

"..., but if your question generally covers …
 -...
 -...
 -software tools commonly used by programmers
 -...
… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!",

it seems alright to ask that kind of question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a library you need to do two things:

1) Add a reference to the file(DLL) containing the library. You do this by adding the reference in solution explorer.

2) Add the open statement to your program (as you did).

SO as things stand you simply need to add the reference.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried to do 1) after opening the reference solution explorer I checked the "FSharp.PowerPack" button (the only button that was checked beforehand was "FSharp.Core"). However, when hitting "OK", I get an error message claiming that the reference to "FSharp.PowerPack" could not be added because such an reference (with the assembly name "FSharp.PowerPack"") was already there...

Comment: I just used NuGet to install the Powerpack to a project in VS 2012 and it added 4 DLLS: Fsharp.PowerPack, Fsharp.PowerPack.Linq, Fsharp.PowerPack.Metadata and Fsharp.PowerPack.Parallel.Seq. Withe these DLLs the reference to Microsoft.FSharp.Text.Lexing is resolved. Sorry I don't know which particular DLL it is in.

Comment: Ok, it seems a bit weird, but after I unchecked the FSharp.PowerPack option but still checked Fsharp.PowerPack.Linq, Fsharp.PowerPack.Metadata and Fsharp.PowerPack.Parallel.Seq. It worked to add these references. Unfortunately It still wouldnt compile before I manually copy-pasted the fsyacc and fslex executables from the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\FSharpPowerPack-4.0.0.0\bin into the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE ...thanks for your effort again